# url trouble passing json from js to java

Tags: javascript, java, json, tomcat, url

No change made at the code, simply I installed an application (struts2) developed using tomcat 8.0.23 on new environment that uses 8.0.50.
The problem is in sending a short json from client (javascript) to server (java).
In the former version I was using an url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:10080/dlq/updprat?jsonparams={%22datavz%22:%2209/04/2018%2014:18:12%22,%22descavz%22:%22foo%20foo%22,%22idprat%22:32,%22codprat%22:%22123456%22,...etc...,costs%22:[]}&pratAffidateSearchType=a
```

and all was running fine.
Now the system returns me the following error:

> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing
>   HTTP request header
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the
>   request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC
>   3986

I localized the error in the braces: those aren't accepted anymore!
how can I remedy the problem?
The app don't use ajax framework (like jQuery or Dojo) and I prefer not to insert tons of libraries now, only for once, for a trivial use.
Is there a plan javascript solution more elegant and universal and exportable instead ofsubstitute the braces at the origin with another character and replace this at destination before parsing?

Answer (score 1):

The `{` symbol should be replaced with `%7B` and `}` with `%7D`.

The easiest way would be to do something like:

```
window.encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
    "datavz":"09/04/2018 14:18:12",
    "descavz":"foo foo",
    "idprat":32,
    "codprat":"123456",
    "costs":[]
}));

// %7B%22datavz%22%3A%2209%2F04%2F2018%2014%3A18%3A12%22%2C%22descavz%22%3A%22foo%20foo%22%2C%22idprat%22%3A32%2C%22codprat%22%3A%22123456%22%2C%22costs%22%3A%5B%5D%7D
```

You shouldn't need to replace this at destination before parsing, since that should be done automatically as it is URL encoded, and it coming from the URL.

Comment: thanx Dave, I'm going to try.  
Someone knows why this change of policy? There's a real improvement in Tomcat performance? and, in Tomcat 8.5 and 9, there,s the same policy?